# jQuery eq(0) not working for me

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show the first div using the following;

```
$('#period-to-view').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Jan") {
        $('div.six-month-view:eq(0)').show();
        $('div.three-month-view').hide();
    } else {
        $('div.three-month-view').show();
        $('div.six-month-view').hide();
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "Jul") {
        $('div.six-month-view:eq(1)').show();
        $('div.three-month-view').hide();
    } else {
        $('div.three-month-view').show();
        $('div.six-month-view').hide();
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that :eq(0) does not work, but :eq(1) does (shows the second div). The markup is a select box that shows a div based on which month is selected (Jan or Jun).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it's because if val=='Jan' it executes the `else` in the second `if` where you hide `.six-month-view` again.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i didn't mean to attack anyone, it just looked like a mistake i myself could lose half an hour on. But i can see it could be coming across the wrong way so fair enough.

Comment: No worries. `Hah` can be interpreted as `Gotcha` rather than `Ah` by a surprisingly high number of people, I was just trying to point that out (Summer of Love being in full effect and all... :)